# Return Single column from HasOne laravel from model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relation

I have the user image saved on a different table and I want to have the following in `User` model

```
public function Image()
{
    return $this->hasOne(UserImages::class, 'user_id', 'id')->latest();
}
```

The above relation returns the following.

```
"image": {
    "id": 3,
    "user_id": 1,
    "image": "http://live.test/uploads/user/User-Oss8MewXVzHZCehHoOUgkdYoo3N1K0gYI9jY69ZsnyiHnqHsHv.png",
    "is_primary": 1,
    "created_at": "2021-04-12T08:01:47.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-04-12T08:01:47.000000Z"
},
```

I want to receive only image, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

use value() method

```
$user->image()->value('image');
```

From [Eloquent documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#retrieving-a-single-row-column-from-a-table)

> If you don't need an entire row, you may extract a single value from a record using the value method. This method will return the value of the column directly:
>
> $email = DB::table('users')->where('name', 'John')->value('email');

You can set it as a user attribute.

```
public function getProfileImageAttribute()
{
    return optional($this->image)->image;
    //or
    return $this->image->image ?? null; 
    //or
    return $this->image->image ?? 'path/of/default/image';
}
```

now you can call it like this

```
$user->profile_image;
```

Comment: Thank you but, Is there anything I can do in Model itself?

Comment: You can set it as an attribute of the User model.

Comment: @Gaurav have you tested it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create another function inside your model and access the previous method like

```
public function image()
{
  return $this->hasOne(UserImages::class, 'user_id', 'id')->latest();
}

public function avatar()
{
  return $this->image->image ?: null;
  //OR
  return $this->image->image ?? null;
  //OR
  return !is_null($this->image) ? $this->image->image : null;
  //OR
  return optional($this->image)->image;
}
```

And it will be accessible with `$user->avatar();`

**As from discussion you are sending response to api**

```
$this->user = $this->user->where('id', "!=", $current_user->id)->with(['chats','Image:user_id,image'])->paginate(50);
```

This will help you, but it will be better to use Resources for api responses to transform some specific fields.

Comment: What if the Image function is returning null?

Comment: You can write conditions on it.

Comment: Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null.

Comment: use optional method on the relation returned

Comment: I used first method it gives `Trying to get property 'image' of non-object` and other gives Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null

Comment: Look first make sure your relation returns result, you can use tinker for that also. After that try to return only that relational function inside avatar method, if it returns data then just take only image from that and it will work. Also make sure you don't have image field in a user table, if it is the case then you need to change the relationship method name to something else because it won't work then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231026/discussion-between-gaurav-and-akhtar-munir).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the magic Laravel provided:

```
$user->image->pluck('profile_image');
```

Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck