# Laravel - Modify Fetched Data With Pagination

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-pagination

I want to format some column fetched from database but didn't know how. I use Laravel 8.x. Here's the snippet :

GarageController.php

```
$q = Garage::with('relative')->paginate(15);
return response()->json($q);
```

the output

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 39819,
      "name": "john",
      "date": "2020-12-20", // i want to format this with date_format()
      "relative": {
        "rid": 912039,
        "rname": "ROV" // and i just want this value instead of all columns
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 38178,
      "name": "danny",
      "date": "2020-12-20", // and this too
      "relative": {
        "rid": 182738,
        "rname": "YIV"
      }
    }
  ],
  "links": {
    .....
  },
  "meta": {
     ....
  }
}
```

The model, the garage have is belong to relative (relative could have many garage).

```
public function relative() {
   return $this->belongsTo(Relative::class, 'relative', 'rid');
}
```

I tried accessor, but it didn't change anything

```
public function getDateAttributes($value) {
  return date_format(date_create($value), 'd/m/Y');
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to remove `s` from the `getDateAttributes`

From

```
public function getDateAttributes($value) {
  return date_format(date_create($value), 'd/m/Y');
}
```

To

```
public function getDateAttribute($value) {
  return date_format(date_create($value), 'd/m/Y');
}
```

Comment: Thank you! God I miss that. Also, how do I modify `relative` column to be `"relative": "ROV"` instead of `"relative" : { "rid": 182738, "rname": "ROV"}` ? should i use the accessor too?

Comment: Yes, you can modify it but instead of that, I prefer that add the virtual column on that modal and return this relation column on the response.  Also can you please approved my answer and upvote me that will encourage me to help more people.

Comment: i tried upvote but i need 15 reputation . So, like, in js, just access it like this `data[0].relative.rname` ?

Comment: Add one virtual column in a modal like `protected $appends = ['relativename'];` and in the accessor of that field, you need to return the value. Or follow the below URL that will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67054990/return-single-column-from-hasone-laravel-from-model